# Issue in clicking on the browse button with selenium in IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am Clicking on the browse button in IE using Selenium Webdriver code in an upload file utility by reading the co-ordinates of the browse text. Whlie the code works fine in some machines in IE and firefox both, in yet another machine the same code is working for firefoxx but the browse button becomes unclickable in IE. We checked the settings in internet options, everything looks alike in both machines.
Please let us know if anyone faced any such issue and the resolution that could work.

Comment: you should provide some more detailes information.

Comment: You shouldn't be clicking the button at all. If you are trying to upload a file, there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any other way to upload the file in your app by avoiding the "Browser" button method, then that is always preferred.  Some people will use [Apache HTTPComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) to do a POST upload to the servlet that the "Browse" button refers to.  That is by far the preferred method rather than using WebDriver.   The problem with the Browse button is that it opens native OS controls ( in some cases) and the only way you can control those is by using the [Sikuli API](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.sikuli%7Csikuli-api%7C1.0.2%7Cjar) to click on elements based on finding them with matching screenshots.   Also, if you use Sikuli, you can't run multiple browser tests on the same machine since each test will block screen comparisons of another test and that will rule you out of using RemoteWebDriver.